# cxf outbound and inbound -endpoint Mule 3.6

Tags: web-services, mule

We are looking to migrate a peice of old mule xml code to Mule 3.6 and I am having issues with this particular functionality

```
<cxf:outbound-endpoint address="${business.process.one}"
                                   proxy="true"
                                   synchronous="true"
                                   transformer-refs="domToXml logging extractIDTransformer stripOutContentIds logging xmlToXSR"
                                   applyTransformersToProtocol="false">
                <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN" timeout="60000"/>
                <property key="outInterceptors" value-ref="cxfOutInterceptors"/>
                <property key="inInterceptors" value-ref="cxfResponseOutboundInterceptors"/>
            </cxf:outbound-endpoint>
```

And various inbound cxf endpoint address as well as it says

> Element cxf:outbound-endpoint is not allowed here

Is there a new way of doing this in Mule 3.6?

Answer (score 0):

Sample should looks like this, select the operation based on your requirement  'client' or 'service' . Interceptors can be selector based on In and out. It will be simple. Refer: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/cxf-module-reference more details

```
 <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="CXF" configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration" serviceClass="co.test.ServiceHttpGet" validationEnabled="true">
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <spring:ref bean="inInterceptorBean"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <spring:ref bean="outInterceptorBeans"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:jaxws-service>
```

Comment: What is this service class? Why do i need to specify this? My endpoint is a business process